# Fix "half-installed" package

Tags: apt, package-management, google-chrome, dpkg

I have the latest google chrome but accidentally tried to install the .deb package i downloaded two years ago, then cancelled with ctrl-c when it was unpacking, now it keeps telling me its half installed (although i'm using the latest version) is there a way to fix this?

Reading a couple of similar questions i've found most of them rely on removing and installing again the package but i don't want to go through all of that trouble, this chrome installation has been running smooth for over a year and it has all my internet history, bookmarks, addons and configurations and it would be silly to spend so much time to backup all of that to fix a progam that is working fine just to remove that silly error message.

I already tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f` without luck.

Is there anything else i could try or ill have to live with it?

Comment: Reinstall google chrome.

Comment: Connect your google chrome browser with google account, it will backup automatically

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the error message. The installation of a newer Chrome release does nothing with your private data/history/addons/….

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest installing the same deb file again. Then you will be able to remove it.

Comment: I deleted the package

Comment: Then try to install the new one.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have had some stubborn packages, that wouldnt uninstall properly. (Im not sure why that happens, package quality perhaps?) anyhow, 
try: `sudo apt-get purge <package>`

Then you might also use `find`, or `locate` to locate any residual files that you might want to remove. places for concern might include anything that is in one of the directories located within the `$PATH` variable.

So if I did sudo apt-get purge xyz
then got:

```
 sudo locate xyz
/usr/bin/xyz/files
/opt/xyz
/home/user/.xyz
```

...
I would investigate the files in /opt and /usr/bin first. 
You may need to do `sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/xyz`

So be cautious. If you find files for the old package installation, or you're uncertain, post back here with what those are, and we can try to assist/ advise. Incidentally, what is the package you are trying to remove / install?